# Subtract values from different times in same pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series like this one:

```
            value     identifier
2007-01-01  0.781611      55
2007-01-01  0.766152      56
2007-01-01  0.766152      57
2007-01-03  0.733152      57
2007-01-12  0.766152      57
2007-02-01  0.705615      55
2007-02-01  0.032134      56 
2007-02-07  0.132134      56 
2007-02-01  0.032134      57
2008-01-01  0.026512      55
2008-01-01  0.993124      56
2008-01-01  0.993124      57
2008-01-11  0.226512      56
2008-02-01  0.226420      55
2008-02-01  0.033860      56
2008-02-01  0.033860      57
2008-02-14  0.333860      55
2008-02-24  0.334860      57
```

Now I want to calculate the differences with different time deltas. My first approach was to

```
last_date = '2008-02-30'
dt = datetime.timedelta(days=30)
delta_30d = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_date, "%Y-%m-%d") - dt
df.loc[last_date]['value'] - df.loc[delta_30d]['value']
```

but if the exact same date on the time delta doesn't exist, I get

```
'the label [2008-01-30 00:00:00] is not in the [index]'
```

So this is a no go. How can I get the closest date from the requested time delta and calculate the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If your index was unique, you could use `DateTimeIndex.asof`, as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115547/find-closest-row-of-dataframe-to-given-time-in-pandas).

Another way (from that same question) would be to use `numpy.argmin` to find the closest date.  For example, you could do

```
In [138]: import numpy as np

In [139]: last_date = pd.Timestamp('2008-01-30')

In [140]: delta_30d = last_date - pd.Timedelta(30, 'D')

In [142]: np.argmin(np.abs(df.index - delta_30d))
Out[142]: 13

In [144]: df.iloc[13, :]
Out[144]: 
value          0.22642
identifier    55.00000
Name: 2008-02-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64

In [145]: df.iloc[np.argmin(np.abs(df.index - last_date))]['value'] - df.iloc[np.argmin(np.abs(df.index - delta_30))]['value']
Out[145]: 0.19990799999999997
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can apply this to all values in a column?

Comment: This actually is not working properly if the index has repeated values for dates.