# Finding nearest time in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I have two different time format dataset like that

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [1499503900, 1512522054, 1412525061, 1502527681, 1512532303]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'B' : ['2017-12-15T11:47:58.119Z', '2017-05-31T08:27:41.943Z', '2017-06-05T14:44:56.425Z', '2017-05-30T16:24:03.175Z' , '2017-07-03T10:20:46.333Z', '2017-06-16T10:13:31.535Z' , '2017-12-15T12:26:01.347Z', '2017-06-15T16:00:41.017Z', '2017-11-28T15:25:39.016Z', '2017-08-10T08:48:01.347Z'] })
```

I need to find the nearest date for each data in the first dataset. Doesn't matter how far is it. Just needed the nearest time. For example:

```
1499503900 for '2017-07-03T10:20:46.333Z'
1512522054 for '2017-12-15T12:26:01.347Z'
1412525061 for '2017-05-31T08:27:41.943Z'
1502527681 for '2017-08-10T08:48:01.347Z'
1512532303 for '2017-06-05T14:44:56.425Z'
```

here is a few help:
This is for converting to long format date :

```
def time1(date_text):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") 
    return calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple())

x = '2017-12-15T12:26:01.347Z'
print(time1(x))
```

out: 1513340761

And this is for converting to ISO format:

```
def time_covert(time):
    seconds_since_epoch = time
    DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)
    return DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch).isoformat()

y = 1499503900
print(time_covert(y))
```

out = 2017-07-08T08:51:40

Any idea will be extremely useful.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find closest row of DataFrame to given time in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115547/find-closest-row-of-dataframe-to-given-time-in-pandas)

Comment: dear djangoliv. I believe I read this document carefully.But I don't understand how to transcribe it to my code. Would you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here a quick start:

```
def time_covert(time):
    seconds_since_epoch = time
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)

# real time series
df2['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['B'])
df2.index = df2['B']
del df2['B']

for a in df1['A']:
    print( time_covert(a))
    i = np.argmin(np.abs(df2.index.to_pydatetime() - time_covert(a)))
    print(df2.iloc[i])
```

Comment: Hi djangoliv, thanks for your answer. But I have a little problem that I havent sloved. Actually I'm working on nested json data( about 24000 json data). I tried to apply your answer on it. like that :

Comment: for k in range(0,21443,1):
        df2['rows'][k]['date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['rows'][k]['date'], unit='s')
        df2.index = df2['rows'][k]['date']
       del df2['rows'][k]['date']

Comment: but It gave me : Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, Timestamp('2017-05-08 15:23:56') was passed. It reads only for first data. I already search for it. It says that I need to create a dataframe for index. But It is already created. So what do u think ?

Comment: I can't help without your data file. But maybe you don't need to loop over rows.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to approach this as an algorithmic question rather than pandas specific. My approach is to sort the "df2" series and for each DateTime in df1, perform a binary search on the sorted df2, to get the indexes of insertion. Then check the indexes just below and above the found index to get the desired output.

Here is the code for above procedure.

> Use standard pandas DateTime for easy comparison

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'A': pd.to_datetime([1499503900, 1512522054, 1412525061, 1502527681, 1512532303], unit='s')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'B' : pd.to_datetime(['2017-12-15T11:47:58.119Z', '2017-05-31T08:27:41.943Z', '2017-06-05T14:44:56.425Z', '2017-05-30T16:24:03.175Z' , '2017-07-03T10:20:46.333Z', '2017-06-16T10:13:31.535Z' , '2017-12-15T12:26:01.347Z', '2017-06-15T16:00:41.017Z', '2017-11-28T15:25:39.016Z', '2017-08-10T08:48:01.347Z']) })
```

> sort df2 according to dates, and get the position of insertion using binary search

```
df2 = df2.sort_values('B').reset_index(drop=True)
ind = df2['B'].searchsorted(df1['A'])
```

> Now check for the minimum difference between the index just above and just below the position of the insertion

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    i = ind[index]
    if i not in df2.index:
        print(df2.iloc[i-1]['B'])
    elif i-1 not in df2.index:
        print(df2.iloc[i]['B'])
    else:
        if abs(df2.iloc[i]['B'] - row['A']) > abs(df2.iloc[i-1]['B'] - row['A']):
            print(df2.iloc[i-1]['B'])
        else:
            print(df2.iloc[i]['B'])
```

The test outputs are these, for each value in df1 respectively. (Note: Please recheck your outputs given in the question, they do not correspond to the minimum difference)

```
2017-07-03 10:20:46.333000
2017-11-28 15:25:39.016000
2017-05-30 16:24:03.175000
2017-08-10 08:48:01.347000
2017-11-28 15:25:39.016000
```

The above procedure has the time complexity of `O(NlogN)` for sorting and `O(logN) (N = len(df2))` for finding each output. If the size of "df1" is large this will be a fairly fast approach.