# Efficient way to get row with closest timestamp to a given datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have a big dataframe that contains around 7,000,000 rows of time series data that looks like this

```
timestamp               | values 
2019-08-01 14:53:01     | 20.0
2019-08-01 14:53:55     | 29.0
2019-08-01 14:53:58     | 22.4
...
2019-08-02 14:53:25     | 27.9
```

I want to create a column that is a lag version of 1 day for each row, since my timestamps don't match up perfectly, I can't use the normal `shift()` method.
The result will be something like this:

```
timestamp               | values | lag
2019-08-01 14:53:01     | 20.0   | Nan
2019-08-01 14:53:55     | 29.0   | Nan
2019-08-01 14:53:58     | 22.4   | Nan
...
2019-08-02 14:53:25     | 27.9   | 20.0
```

I found some posts related to get the closest timestamp to a given time: [Find closest row of DataFrame to given time in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115547/find-closest-row-of-dataframe-to-given-time-in-pandas/19974491) and tried the methods, it does the job but takes too long to run, here's what I have:

```
def get_nearest(data, timestamp):
    index = data.index.get_loc(timestamp,"nearest")
    return data.iloc[index, 0]
df['lag'] = [get_nearest(df, dt) for dt in df.index]
```

Any efficient ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm, not sure if this will work out to be more efficient, but [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) is an approach worth looking at as won't require a udf.

```
df['date'] = df.timestamp.dt.date
df2 = df.copy()
df2['date'] = df2['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit ='D')
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'] + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit ='D')
pd.merge_asof(df,df2, on = 'timestamp', by = 'date', direction = 'nearest')
```

The approach essentially merges the previous day value to the next day and then matches to the nearest timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are sorted, one way to do this quickly would be to use [`pd.DateTimeIndex.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.searchsorted.html) to find all the matching dates in `O[N log N]` time.

Creating some test data, it might look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'values': np.random.rand(10)},
  index=sorted(np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2019-08-01', freq='T', periods=10000), 10, replace=False))
)

def add_lag(df):
  ind = df.index.searchsorted(df.index - pd.DateOffset(1))
  out_of_range = (ind <= 0) | (ind >= df.shape[0])
  ind[out_of_range] = 0
  lag = df['values'].values[ind]
  lag[out_of_range] = np.nan
  df['lag'] = lag
  return df

add_lag(df)
```

```
                       values       lag
2019-08-01 06:17:00  0.548814       NaN
2019-08-01 10:51:00  0.715189       NaN
2019-08-01 13:56:00  0.602763       NaN
2019-08-02 09:50:00  0.544883  0.715189
2019-08-03 14:06:00  0.423655  0.423655
2019-08-04 03:00:00  0.645894  0.423655
2019-08-05 07:40:00  0.437587  0.437587
2019-08-07 00:41:00  0.891773  0.891773
2019-08-07 07:05:00  0.963663  0.891773
2019-08-07 15:55:00  0.383442  0.891773
```

With this approach, a dataframe with 1 million rows can be computed in tens of milliseconds:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'values': np.random.rand(1000000)},
  index=sorted(np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2019-08-01', freq='T', periods=10000000), 1000000, replace=False))
)

%timeit add_lag(df)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 71.5 ms per loop
```

Note however that this doesn't find the *nearest* value to a lag of one day, but the nearest value *after* a lag of one day. If you want the nearest value in either direction, you'll need to modify this approach.

Comment: I tried it and found out that while I have a record at '2019-08-01 14:53:01' but the 'lag' for '2019-08-02 09:42:46' is 'Nan', wouldn't it show the value for '2019-08-01 14:53:01' since it is the closest to '2019-08-02 09:42:46' minus a day?