# Select row based on the closest hour and date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, select

I have two kind of data, one is dataframe and one is right now many lists contain data regard hours of image aqcuisition, so the data look like this:

the pandas dataframe (has dates and hours from 23/6 -04/07, everyday from 07:00-17:00):

```
>>>timestamp                    date             hour        person_1   person_2 ............
0 2019-06-23 07:00:00          2019-06-23       07:00:00     0.124      0.431
1 2019-06-23 07:03:00          2019-06-23       07:03:00     0.131      0.438
2 2019-06-23 07:06:00          2019-06-23       07:06:00     0.154      0.433
3 2019-06-23 07:09:00          2019-06-23       07:09:00     0.164      0.441
....
2 2019-07-04 16:57:00          2019-07-04       16:57:00     0.864      0.675
3 2019-07-04 17:00:00          2019-07-04       17:00:00     0.823      0.631
```

the hour each image was taken in format of lists (The number after the word Hour is representative of the date) :

```
#Hours that the image was taken
Hours23=['07:00','08:00','09:32','10:14','11:15','12:17','13:03','14:41','15:04','17:05']
Hours24=['07:00','08:13','09:02','10:09','11:02','12:03','14:09','16:00','17:00']
Hours25=['08:15','09:02','10:02','11:02','12:02','14:02','15:02','16:00','17:00']
...
Hours3=['07:00','08:02','09:02','10:02','11:02','12:02','13:03','14:03','15:02','16:01','17:00']
Hours4=['07:15','08:02','12:02','13:03']
```

**I want to select rows in the dataframe base on those lists of hours**,   e.g, to select the the row that is the closest to the Hour of the image .
For example, for 23/6, the first hour of image is 07:00, and than 08:00, then 09:32...
so I would like to have in my dataframe only the rows that t**heir hour is the closest to the image hour.**
I saw there are ways to filter it ,as mentioned here ([Find closest row of DataFrame to given time in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115547/find-closest-row-of-dataframe-to-given-time-in-pandas/19974491)) but I want to take into account the fact that I have differnt hours for each date.

so results should look something like this:

```
>>>timestamp                    date             hour        person_1   person_2 ............
0 2019-06-23 07:00:00          2019-06-23       07:00:00     0.124      0.431
1 2019-06-23 08:01:00          2019-06-23       07:00:00     0.108      0.370
1 2019-06-23 09:32:00          2019-06-23       07:00:00     0.101      0.360
...
```

Comment: Do different months also have the same hours list?

Comment: Yeah, how do you know if Hours24 is for June or July?

Comment: the data is only for june-july so it only have two months, and the hours specific for each day (Hours1=1/7/2019, hour30=30/06/2019 ect.

Comment: to be mroe specifically- dates are between 23/6 to 04/7 so 24 is june for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list of times isn't an ideal format, so I'll show you the approach for one date, where the dataframe `h23` is manually built.  You could code this to build out a dataframe that holds all of the times if you want.

The basic premise is to make a dataframe `h23` for example, with all of the timestamps of the photos.  Use this to merge with the df timestamp, using `pd.merge_asof` which has the ability to do the closest time match.  `nearest` means the actual time could be before of after, but there are options for `backward` and `forward` as well if the time needs to be the nearest time before the event.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': {0: '2019-06-23 07:00:00',
  1: '2019-06-23 07:03:00',
  2: '2019-06-23 07:06:00',
  3: '2019-06-23 07:09:00'},
 'date': {0: '2019-06-23', 1: '2019-06-23', 2: '2019-06-23', 3: '2019-06-23'},
 'hour': {0: '07:00:00', 1: '07:03:00', 2: '07:06:00', 3: '07:09:00'},
 'person_1': {0: 0.124, 1: 0.131, 2: 0.154, 3: 0.16399999999999998},
 'person_2': {0: 0.431, 1: 0.43799999999999994, 2: 0.433, 3: 0.441}})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

Hours23=['07:00','08:00','09:32','10:14','11:15','12:17','13:03','14:41','15:04','17:05']

h23 = pd.DataFrame({'Time':Hours23, 'Day':'2019-06-23'})

h23['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(h23['Day'] + " " + h23['Time'])

pd.merge_asof(h23,df, on='timestamp', direction='nearest').drop(columns=['Day','Time'])
```

Output

```
              timestamp      date       hour    person_1    person_2
0   2019-06-23 07:00:00 2019-06-23  07:00:00    0.124   0.431
1   2019-06-23 08:00:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
2   2019-06-23 09:32:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
3   2019-06-23 10:14:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
4   2019-06-23 11:15:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
5   2019-06-23 12:17:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
6   2019-06-23 13:03:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
7   2019-06-23 14:41:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
8   2019-06-23 15:04:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
9   2019-06-23 17:05:00 2019-06-23  07:09:00    0.164   0.441
```

Comment: Deserves community wiki and 100+ reps. The [post indicated by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115547) seemed to have overlooked `pd.merge_asof()`. This is what `pd.Index.asof()` cannot achieve.